# php get specific json array element tag

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql, laravel-5

First of all I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question but I couldn't find anything that would work and solve my problem.

I'm fetching data from a DB(Postgres) and parsing that into a Json array.
The data looks like this

```
[{"login":"root@localhost","first_name":"Admin","last_name":"Name","title":null},{"login":"another@localhost","first_name":"More","last_name":"Data","title":"X"}]
```

My code to fetch this data is something like this:

```
foreach ($jsonData as $us) {
    $user = new App\User;
    $user->name = $us->login; //same thing for the rest of data
```

The error I'm getting says that I can't call data from the JSON with `->` but var_dump'ing $jsonData states that it's an array with all the correct elements in it.

**PS**: forgot to add but I tried `var_dump($jsonData['login'][0]);` to get just the first login (should be "root@localhost") but it says "Undefined index: login"

Comment: You have your index's backwards when you did `var_dump($jsonData['login'][0]);`.  If you did `var_dump($jsonData[0]['login']);` it should work

Comment: Might be irrelevant but I think your foreach loop is missing a closing `}` ?

Comment: Also as far as the `->` not working.  PHP has a `json_decode()` method which allows a JSON string to be parsed into either an array or an object (based upon a boolean parameter in the function).  I'm assuming your database drive is automatically parsing the data into an array after you query for it.  I'm guessing you seen some examples where the JSON data is an object, thus causing some confusion for you.  Could be wrong, just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: @CJWurtz that's it, actually. I wasn't fully aware that a json could be parsed from a string to an object OR an array. (never assumed there would be a huge difference). But now that I put together my previous uses of json and later experiences with it and Laravel, this actually makes a lot more sense now. Many thanks.

Comment: @lozadaOmr The missing bracket was just a copy error to the post. The code itself is ok. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you JSON is not store in an object, but in a array :

```
foreach ($jsonData as $us) {
    $user = new App\User;
    $user->name = $us['login']; //same thing for the rest of data
}
```

Comment: I must've inadvertedly type something wrong last time I tried this, because now that I did as you sugested it worked just fine. Perhaps it's because I used brackets " " instead of colons ' ' or something like that. Either way, thank you very much for the help!